# Can I upgrade my graphics driver to support the latest OpenGL versions?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, upgrade, opengl

My laptop is a Core 2 Duo Dell from 2008. I am trying to run some OpenGL programs. The program with following code doesn't work:

```
glutInitContextVersion(4, 0);
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

The code requires OpenGL version of 4.0. `glxinfo` suggests OpenGL version 2.1.

- The details of my Intel graphics driver from System Settings are:

  [image]

I don't see anything useful in the additional drivers section, except one Broadcom driver already activated. From Ubuntu Software Centre, I tried searching some other drivers and found Nvidia '173' and 'current' drivers. But I am not sure, if I should install them. Will it break whatever OpenGL programs are running fine?

What should I do to upgrade my graphics driver, so that it starts supporting latest OpenGL version like 4.0 to 4.3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OpenGL support is typically a *hardware* feature, and cannot just be upgraded by installing a new/different driver; the *nvidia* drivers you mention are for discrete Nvidia cards and will do nothing for your Intel graphics.

According to [Intel's documentation](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/intelg965/sb/CS-023713.htm), the 965GM chipset supports only up to OpenGL 1.5.

For OpenGL 4.0+ support, [it appears you will need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#OpenGL_4.0) to upgrade to a new graphics card, which must be one of:

- Intel HD 2500/4000 integrated graphics
- AMD/ATI Radeon HD 5xxx/6xxx/7xxx
- Nvidia GeForce 4xx/5xx/6xx

> Note: this requires purchasing new hardware, probably a new laptop since you appear to be on one.

Comment: Which one to choose among these 3? Is there any command to upgrade it? Thx.

Comment: @iammilind unfortunately, upgrading hardware with a command doesn't work like that. You have to go out and buy the physical device and then upgrade it that way.

Comment: @jrg, got it. I thought it will be as easy as driver upgrade.