# Wifi works perfectly in Windows but incosistent in Ubuntu. Goes up and down frequently

Tags: 12.04, wireless, network-manager

I am facing the problem described in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1903872) and [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1976654).

To describe in brief, my internet wifi faces problem where the internet pages don't load every few minutes and completely stop working. However I see that sometimes the services like skype or even gmail are unaffected. During this time the wifi symbol is continuously says that wifi is connected!

The internet returns after sometime and then the story repeats. Important to note that wifi works perfectly fine with the Windows 7 (dual boot). I have also checked this at my friend's home where wifi has problem with Ubuntu but not with Windows.

I have come across [this post discussing the similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24550/wifi-works-perfectly-on-windows-but-drops-on-ubuntu). Need to try that. However any better/permanent solution is welcome.

**Edit**: I have tried with WICD as mentioned in other links. It doesn't appear to be a *great* improvement for now. I have found [one more askubuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130499/how-do-i-fix-slow-wireless-on-intel-wireless-cards) which I am yet to explore.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: @JorgeCastro, from where exactly to get the hardware details? I had asked [other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176124/can-i-upgrade-my-graphics-driver-to-support-the-latest-opengl-versions) sometime back; is it similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my laptop (with a Broadcom b43 adapter) after installing 12.04. Then I googled and found the answer here. I don't remember the thread, but I don't deserve credit if you solve this problem thanks to my answer.

Make sure you have the wireless driver installed and enabled.

You may need proprietary/restricted drivers.

If you can connect via Ethernet follow these steps:

Connect to internet using an ethernet connection. It will be detected as ato eth0.

Click the **settings** icon on the launcher.

Go to **Restricted drivers**.

If you find your wireless card on the driver list, enable it. The driver will be downloaded and enabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is nothing called "Restricted drivers". Shows only "Additional drivers" , which is already installed.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "Additional Drivers". I was confused because of a pevios ubuntu version in Spanish where" the name meant somethng like restricted drivers in refernce to closed source, proprietary drivers.

Sorry about that. Too bad it didn't work. Many people had problems with the wireless card not being properly detected 8including me, after installing 12.04) and it was a driver issue.

I hope you get better help soon.

Comment: Well, the detection is fine. It's just that internet goes up and down very frequently as mentioned in question. So the problem is about internet **inconsistency**